# Macro Run only if it is a false file name added

Tags: excel, vba, file, if-statement, directory

I have a Macro that Loops through Folder where xlsm file is and finds the File based on a condition to match the given part of the file with the file in Folder and skip it. The file full name is 03_2020_STR_BB_2080.xls. Code works perfectly, but my problem starts when I introduce the correct number in this case. 2080 as shown below. When I click on Run button to run the code the Macro doesn't start at all, but when I insert a False value then instead of 2080 any other number or text that is not a part of a file when I click on Run then Macro starts to Run.
Can anybody help me, tnx in advance.
In my folder are three files

```
03_2020_STR_BB_2080.xls
03_2020_STR_BB_7080.xls
03_2020_STR_BB_2130.xls
```

I am using following part of a code.

```
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Fname As String


Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"


MyFile = Dir(Filepath)


Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

If MyFile = "BB2.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

If MyFile Like "*STR_BB_2080.xls" Then  
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)

code continues....
```

Comment: unclear to me. you could add more clear examples of what doesn't work

Comment: I have added aditional explanation. Its all about that Macro don't start to Run when I click a Run button on True value, It runs perfectly only on FALSE value. It gives me no kind of error message, just doesn't Run.It has something to do with system settings or some files and path runed before in this Macro?

Comment: please add details about what _"click a Run button on True value"_ actually means

Comment: Thanks a lot , I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check by replacing the if condition with this line:

```
If MyFile Like "*STR_BB_2080*" Then
```